# finding privilege and sensitive instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, arm

In a given isa ( lets say x86 or arm ) is there any way to figure out that the particular instruction is privilege or sensitive ?/
We can see the documentation and can conclude this, but by using assembly instruction is this possible to figure out this ?

Edit : Moreover documents of all the isa doesn't specify whether the instruction is sensitive like arm ( though x86 clearly specifies this). So there should be way to figure this out.

Comment: Most assembly language's don't include any meta-programming facilities. If you *know* that you're running unprivileged, you may be able to execute the instruction and get notified of the violation, but how to do so would be OS/Environment specific.

Answer (score 1):

Hook the PrivilegeException vector (or equivalent) to point to a handler which reports the fault. Execute an instruction. If you don't see the exception, it's not privileged.

Comment: what about sensitive instruction, which can change the privilege data structure without even notifying or Protection fault ?

Comment: I'm not sure that a privileged data structure (e.g. an interrupt vector table) would necessarily be accessible from User Mode - that is to say, the CPU would have to be in Supervisor Mode (or equivalent) in order to be able to modify it. However, the instructions would not necessarily be anything other than 'normal' ones, it's just that they are executing at a higher privilege level. So I don't think there's an easy way to detect that a specific instruction is inherently sensitive, since its' sensitivity depends on execution context...